# C array arithmetic and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, integer-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

I am reading through a tutorial on C and I came across this syntax:

```
int doses[] = {1, 3, 2, 1000};
doses[3] == *(doses + 3) == *(3 + doses) == 3[doses]
```

Now the point is to get the `int 1000`, but the last one doesn't make any sense. Either its late and my brain is not functioning, its something specific to C, or its a typo. I want to cover all my basics when it comes to pointers so reading through it carefully. That means understanding it all. Any answers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Accessing_elements)

> Since the expression a[i] is semantically equivalent to *(a+i), which in turn is equivalent to *(i+a), the expression can also be written as i[a], although this form is rarely used.

Comment: "*... as i[a], although this form is rarely used.*": Yes, very rarely.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate the timely response. That just made no sense to me coming from Java and PHP, but semantically I guess I can live with that.

Comment: @alk it's still good enough for obfuscation, though.

Comment: @Andy I'll be honest with you, I had no idea either. I googled "c array syntax" and this was the first result.

Comment: @alk also note the syntax `&(a[b])` which is equivalent to `a+b` and also works for non-pointers.

Comment: Really? Haha. I didn't think I'd get anything. Thats embarrassing. But hey, now its an actual question on here :D

Comment: @Andy I agree, it's an interesting question!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, array subscripting is commutative in C. `e1[e2]` is indeed the same as `*((e1)+(e2))`. But it is useless in production code, and the only purpose of this notation is to make obfuscated source code.

Comment: I'm curious if you know the reason as to why this decision was made in the design of array/pointer arithmetic? I agree it seems useless and not to mention confusing. But I guess now that I know it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: @Andy: When C programming langage was designed, compilers didn't have enough memory to perform a lot of syntax check. So translating `E1[E2]` to `*((E1)+(E2))` reduced the cost of the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

```
ISO c99 : 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
```

1
 One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to object type’’, the other expression shall
have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.

```
E1[E2] either E1 will be pointer to object type and E2 will be integer type.
```

Or,

```
E1 is integer type and E2 is of pointer to that type
```

as `+` is commutative so `E1[E2] == E2[E1]` , because it's actually evaluated as `(*(E1+E2))`